# AttributeError: 'LoginTest' object has no attribute 'lp'

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, ui-automation

After running the following unit test, I got the error: `AttributeError: 'LoginTest' object has no attribute 'lp'`

```
from pages.home.login_page import LoginPage
import unittest
import pytest

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("oneTimeSetUp", "setUp")
class LoginTest(unittest.TestCase):

       @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
       def classSetUp(self, oneTimeSetUp):
             self.lp = LoginPage(self.driver)

       @pytest.mark.run(order=2)
       def test_validLogin(self):
             self.lp.login("xxxxx", "test1234")
             result = self.lp.verifyLoginSuccessful()
             assert result == True
             #self.driver. quit()

        @pytest.mark.run(order=1)
        def test_invalidLogin(self):
             self.driver.get(self.baseUrl)
             self.lp.login("xxxxx", "11111")
             result = self.lp.verifyLoginFailed()
             assert result == True
```

The attribute `lp` is defined in method `classSetUp`. What am I missing here?

Comment: Don't include all this code if the error is clearly related to the first part only. Moreover, be more careful with the formatting, many lines where not displayed as code.

Answer (score 1):

The error is exactly as it says: the `LoginTest` class has no attribute `lp` - you're attempting to assign to something that doesn't exist.

You'll want to define an `__init__` method for `LoginTest` as well and initialise `lp` there.